# how to merge two arrays in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays

i want to merge two array, but how?

```
$array1 [ ] = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => "Alice" ))

$array2 [] = Array ( [0] => Array ( [age] => 22 ));
```

The result array i want to get:

```
$result  = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1   [name] => "Alice"     [age] => 22) );
```

anyone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is only single array entry then you can try this otherwise you have to apply loop for complete set of arrays

```
$result[] = $array1[0] + $array2[0];
```

//    print_r($result  );

it will give you output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Alice
            [age] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: hi, thanks! this solve my problem! finally, i use $result[] = $array1+$array2. it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

```
array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Iter through array1. If the first Element is always an array, just add the elements of array2[c] to the array array1[c], where c is the counting variable.

Comment: looping through an array to merge stuff in is a waste of CPU time in simple cases, when there's functions like `array_merge` available.